# Dropdown Menu Blogspot

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, blogger

My Blogspot Template uses the following Code to show pages in a dropdown menu in the mobile version: https://www.topfgartenwelt.com/2013/10/goldene-tage-ade.html?m=1. But it always displays "Startseite". I don't want that. Is there a way to show "Impressum" in the menu instead of "Startseite"?

```
<b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'><h4><data:title/></h4></b:if>
  <div class='widget-content'>
    <b:if cond='data:mobile'>
      <label><b>Impressum:</b><select expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_select&quot;'>
        <b:loop values='data:links' var='link'>
          <option expr:value='data:link.href'>
           <b:attr cond='data:link.isCurrentPage' name='selected' value='selected'/>
            <data:link.title/>
          </option>
        </b:loop>
       </select></label>
     <!-- <span class='pagelist-arrow'>&amp;#9660;</span> -->
    <b:else/>
      <ul>
        <b:loop values='data:links' var='link'>
          <li>
            <b:class cond='data:link.isCurrentPage' name='selected'/>
            <a expr:href='data:link.href'><data:link.title/></a>
            </li>
        </b:loop>
      </ul>
    </b:if>
    <b:include name='quickedit'/>
  </div>
```